# LookupRows Data Extension error in the email preview

Tags: lookup, ampscript, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Once I try to do a preview of the email the next error appears:

> The Data Extension name for a LookupRows function call is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does not exist. Data Extension Name:
>
> Registered_Fam_Members Function Call: LookupRows("Registered_Fam_Members","PersonContactId",_subscriberkey)
>
> Parameter Name: DataExtensionName Parameter Ordinal: 1

That Data Extension exists an the `AMPScript` code I am using is `%%=LookupRows("Registered_Fam_Members","PersonContactId",_subscriberkey)=%%`

The Data Extension that is being used as sendable is a Standard one.

Do you know what this issue could be related with?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the ENT. prefix in the DE name and now it works.